# Check Whether Another Component Has Rendered Before calling JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

First watch this, so you can see the behavior going on.

[Timing Issue](https://youtu.be/9dIRR32HkH8) (JS in one component relies on another component to exist first)

I need to be able to somehow check that another component exists before I apply this JS in this component's ComponentDidMount

```
const TableOfContents = Component({
    store: Store('/companies'),
    componentDidMount() {
        const el = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this);
        console.log("table of contents mounted");
        if(document.getElementById('interview-heading') && el) {

            new Ink.UI.Sticky(el, {topElement: "#interview-heading", bottomElement: "#footer"});
        }
    },
```

it does hit my if statement and does hit the Sticky() function but I still think I have problems when I refresh the page whereas this JS isn't working on the interview-heading component for some reason.

Note the `id="interview-heading"` below.

```
const InterviewContent = Component({
    componentDidMount() {
        console.log("InterviewContent mounted");
    },
    render(){
        var company = this.props.company;

        return (
            <div id="ft-interview-content">
                <p className="section-heading bold font-22" id="interview-heading">Interview</p>
                <InterviewContentMain company={company}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
})

const InterviewContentMain = Component({
    componentDidMount() {
        console.log("InterviewContentMain mounted");
    },
        render(){
            var company = this.props.company;

            return (
                <div id="interview-content" className="clear-both">
                    <div className="column-group">
                        <div className="all-20">
                            <TableOfContents company={company}/>
                        </div>
                        <div className="all-80">
                            <InterviewContainer company={company}/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            )
        }
    })



export default InterviewContent;
```

I realize TableOfContents is being rendered before InterviewContent because it's a child of TableOfContents and I believe in React children are rendered before their parents (inside-out)?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to rethink your component structure. I don't know your entire setup, but it looks like you should probably have a shared parent component pass the message from `TableOfContents` to `InterviewContent`:

```
const InterviewContentMain = Component({
    getInitialState() {
        return {
            inkEnabled: false
        }
    },
    componentDidMount() {
        console.log("InterviewContentMain mounted");
    },
    enableInk() {
        this.setState({ inkEnabled: true });
    }
    render(){
        var company = this.props.company;

        return (
            <div id="interview-content" className="clear-both">
                <div className="column-group">
                    <div className="all-20">
                        <TableOfContents inkEnabled={this.state.inkEnabled} company={company}/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="all-80">
                        <InterviewContainer enableInk={this.enableInk} company={company}/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
})

const TableOfContents = Component({
   store: Store('/companies'),
   componentDidMount() {
      console.log("table of contents mounted");
      this.props.enableInk();
   },
   ...

const InterviewContent = Component({
    enableInk() {
        new Ink.UI.Sticky(el, {topElement: "#interview-heading", bottomElement: "#footer"});
    },
    // willReceiveProps isn't called on first mount, inkEnabled could be true so 
    componentDidMount() {
        if (this.props.inkEnabled) {
            this.enableInk();
        }
    },
    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        if (this.props.inkEnabled === false && nextProps.inkEnabled === true) {
            this.enableInk();
        }
    }
    render(){
        var company = this.props.company;

        return (
            <div id="ft-interview-content">
                <p className="section-heading bold font-22" id="interview-heading">Interview</p>
                <InterviewContentMain company={company}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
})
```

Then have `componentDidMount` trigger `this.props.enableInk()`.

Or better yet, why not just put the `Ink.UI.Sticky` call in `componentDidMount` of `InterviewContent`?

Comment: so by setting state on the parent, that is doing what for me...meaning how is that making this work?  Does that trigger the parent to be rendered before TableOfContents?

Comment: I also see you listed the components backwards, starting with TableOfContents first...?

Comment: I'm saying that you would use that `prop` (which comes down from the parent state) as your check, rather than using a DOM lookup. I'll try to update my example

Comment: right but just trying to understand how the parent state plays here, in the lifecycle.  Trying to understand how setting state before render() is helping me ensure that TableOfContents is called after InterviewContent is rendered since InterviewContent contains that interview-header <p>

Comment: oh so since InterviewContent is calling enableLink() that causes the parent's state to be updated right?  If so I still don't understand how TableOfContents is waiting to be rendered.  I'd think since TableOfContents is the first, it'll be rendered first?  Or does React render from bottom up order, starting with InterviewContentMain first, then InterviewContent is rendered, then TableOfContents is rendrered in that order?

Comment: "oh so since InterviewContent is calling enableLink() that causes the parent's state to be updated right?" Exactly - trying to make a more realistic example for you

Comment: gotcha, and then since the parent's state is updated, I can say hey, TableOfContents now you can use Ink, because we know that InterviewContent just got done rendering

Comment: Was I right about the ordering of child component rendering?  or is it that it doesn't necessarily render them in that order, that react orders components in parallel (async)?

Comment: The rendering is not really deterministic - they are rendered in parallel and it can take more time to render one than the other for myriad reasons. It's best if sibling components don't *directly* interact with each other, as you have no guarantee that they will be available in any of the lifecycle methods. Instead, opt for message passing to a shared parent and you can use `willReceiveProps`, `componentWillUpdate`, etc. to trigger functionality like this

Comment: to answer your last question "Or better yet, why not just put the Ink.UI.Sticky call in componentDidMount of InterviewContent?".  Because when I do that, the Table of Contents, nor the InterviewContent stick below the Interview Header <p>, so I lose the stickiness completely.

Comment: Ok, my example is updated (hopefully it makes more sense) - also - makes sense why you don't use componentDidMount

Comment: thanks for updating.  What if TableOfContents renders before InterviewContentMain.  Wouldn't that mean inkEnabled  be false in those cases so it'd never fire off the INK?  I'm gonna try your idea in a second, just thinking in my head on first review.

Comment: well good thing is your implementation fixed my timing issue thanks!  I might have to change it a bit, I needed my TableOfContents to stay stuck below the interview-header and it's not but that shouldn't be a big deal to figure out at this point.  Thanks much, I'm new to React so this will teach me a lot about the cycle.

Comment: Glad to help! To answer your question `TableOfContents` cannot render before its parent, so you should not run in to that situation.

Comment: parents always render first, makes sense, they're the parent

Comment: well your code actually isn't working.  The table of contents still renders before the other two :(

Comment: in your example I don't think this.props.enableInk(); will work in TableOfContents because you hadn't passed it that prop